# How can I candlestick data grouping in highcharts for different timeframe by laravel

Tags: laravel, highcharts

I try to create a candlestick chart by highchart , I made a chart successfully but i have one difficulty that i not know how to group different timeframe data series ,

example , 1minute 5 minutes 15 minutes 1 hour 4 hour 1 day etc  ....

to do this groups , what database need ?

in my Open High Low Close price data , I take them depend on day timeframe from database by laravel .

as follow

```
   $currenttime = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
     

        $date =Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d');
       
        $pricelist = Sell::whereDate('created_at', '=', $date)->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

     

       $priceHL = Sell::whereDate('created_at', '=', $date)->orderBy('price','asc')->get();
   

         $openprice = $pricelist->first()->price;
         $closeprice = $pricelist->last()->price;
         $highprice = $priceHL->last()->price;
         $lowprice = $priceHL->first()->price;
```

I make them to know Open , close , high and low price of this day by compare Carbon format date ,

after that , I send this price data to another table as follow

```
  $datecompare =  Price::orderBy('id','asc')->get()->last()->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
   

        if($date != $datecompare ){
   
           
      
          Price::create([
           
            'openprice' => $openprice,
            'closeprice' => $closeprice,
            'highprice' => $highprice,
            'lowprice' => $lowprice,
           ]);

          }

          if($currenttime == $date ){
        
         Price::whereDate('created_at', '=', $date)->update([
            'openprice' => $openprice,
            'closeprice' => $closeprice,
            'highprice' => $highprice,
            'lowprice' => $lowprice,
           ]);

          }

           $priceall = Price ::get();

       

       return view('chart',compact('priceall'));
```

if current date price data has, filters all price to open close high low and if today not equal to previous day that record in Price table , insert new open close high low price to Price table , So Price table has data to from a candle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaStc.png)

if data has in Prices table , I call them to candlestick chart by Highchart ,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                          // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
                 
                 rangeSelector: {
                     allButtonsEnabled: true,
                 
                 
                       selected: 1
                   },
                 
                   plotOptions: {
                            candlestick: {
                                color: 'red',
                                upColor: 'green'
                            }
                        },
                 
                 title: {
                     text: 'CC Price'
                 },
                 
                 
                 series: [{
                     type: 'candlestick',
                    
                     name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                   
                     data: [
                 
                       <?php  foreach($priceall as $price) 
                 
                           {?>
                     
                             [ <?php echo strtotime($price['created_at']) *1000 ; ?>, <?php echo $price['openprice']; ?>,<?php echo $price['highprice']; ?>, <?php echo $price['lowprice']; ?> ,<?php echo $price['closeprice'] ?> ],
                         
                         <?php  }?>
                         ] ,
                    dataGrouping: {
                          units: [
                            [
                              'week', // unit name
                              [1] // allowed multiples
                            ], [
                              'month',
                              [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                            ]
                          ]
                        }
                 
                 


}]



});
   
      });
```

Candlestick appear ,but i have one problem is how to set different timeframe data group base on this database output on Highcharts ,

What data still need to do different timeframes grouping , Highcharts can make data grouping by reading x values timestamp ?

if so how can do this , I read some articles they said https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.grouping can do this .
but how?
please show me example , I can learn well if there is some examples,

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dataGrouping](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.dataGrouping) the visible time interval between points is set by the array [dataGrouping.units](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.dataGrouping.units).

```
  dataGrouping: {
    enabled: true,
    units: [
      [
        'month',
        [6]
      ],
    ]
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t9me6uo8/1/

Comment: if want to be data group from minutes ,when fetch data from database ,timestamp should start from minutes intervals ?because in your example , show start from day week to month, cannot backward to hour,minutes?

Comment: Units in data grouping are the preferred range from the data in UNIX timestamp format and are then adjusted according to what you set in unit.
If you want to have a visible range in minutes according to the array [15, 30] then Highcharts will take the largest value i.e. 30 minutes.

Comment: although i try as  ` {
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '5Minute',
                        preserveDataGrouping: true,
                        dataGrouping: {
                            forced: true,
                            units: [
                                ['minute', [1,5]]
                            ]
                        }
                    },`,candle range not change,see day candle again with big candle,what wrong in minute data group

Comment: The grouping adapting to the data, for the example I added some data with an interval of seconds. If you select by navigator minutes it groups by minutes in the array [1, 5], first by minutes and then when move navigator to the data with seconds in seconds, as in the [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ck13v04s/).

Comment: you see my codes in my question, my data of OHLC come from day frame , I want to data group them to 5 minutes , how can set them in highcharts, I not get the point with your examples , chart work start from day timeframe to All frame zoom, but not work in minute hour frame,How can do that in rangeSelector

Comment: Sorry I don't get your idea, could you explain what do you want to achieve?  "not work in minute hour frame, How can do that in rangeSelector ", how do you want grouping data?

Comment: please check code https://codepen.io/jetli07/pen/poZwvop , my price data based on hour(60minutes) and 1Hr timeframe work well , but 4hr timeframe not work , 1D , 1week and All timeframe work well, please help me how can fix for 4hr in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251113/discussion-between-koleo-and-sebastian-hajdus).